# Apply start of month to previous tax year: Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am trying to write a macro that loops through a sort table, creates a copy of template for each financial year it finds then copies and pastes the data from the sort table into the appropriate cells on the corresponding worksheet.

I have code that loops through the data and creates a copy of the worksheet for each financial year.

I have written the bit that loops through the sort table and returns the variables I need in order to paste payment data to the correct Worksheet:
-Tax year Year (Which is what I have named the worksheets),
-Financial Month which dictates the destination column and
-Charge Type which decides the destination column and Cash which is the value I want to copy and paste.

The functions FY (returns the financial year) and FM (returns the Financial month) from a string with the date in format DD.MM.YYYY.
I use these functions to create variables that provides the co-ordinates for where I want call values pasted.

```
Worksheets(TY).Cells(16, Cashcol).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Cash
```

TY= Year (What I have used to name the worksheets.
16 is the last row in the range I want to copy to.
Cashcol is the column I want.
xlUp is a constant *edited because I didn't know this when I first asked the question*.

This works for all dates between 5th of May to 31st of April. (Month’s 1 to most of 12.)

Due to the Tax year running 6th April to 5th April there is a period from 1st of May to 4th of May l that belongs in the previous Tax Year.

This means that FM returns a month of 0.

To fix this I added the lines:

```vb
If Cashmonth = 0 Then Backyear = True
      
If Backyear = True Then TY = FY(EDP) - 1
If Backyear = True Then Cashcol = 51
```

EG. 03.05.2023 is in Month 12 of 2022 Tax Year.
Which I want to go to first empty cell above row 16 in column 51 of the worksheet named 2022.

I get an error that doesn’t happen when Backyear=false.

> Subscript out of range

Debugging shows that all other variables are correct (TY =2022, Cashcol = 51, Cash= the correct amount). xlUp returns -4162 *which I now know is correct*.

How have I managed to break what, outside of 5 days in May, is a working code?

Slightly redacted version of the full code:

```vb
Option Explicit


Public Function FY(Fdate As String) As String
Dim arDMY As Variant

arDMY = Split(Fdate, ".")
If arDMY(1) >= 5 Then
   FY = CStr(arDMY(2) + 1)
Else
  FY = CStr(arDMY(2))
End If
End Function


Public Function FM(Fdate As String) As String
Dim arDMY As Variant
Dim TM As String
arDMY = Split(Fdate, ".")
If arDMY(1) >= 5 Then
   TM = CStr(arDMY(1) - 4)
Else
  TM = CStr(arDMY(1) + 8)
End If

If arDMY(0) >= 5 Then
   FM = TM
Else
  FM = TM - 1
End If
End Function


Sub Move_stuff()
Dim cell As Range
Dim Todate As Range
Dim Charge As Range
Dim Duedate As Range

Dim Sort_Table As Worksheet
Dim Template As Worksheet

Dim C As Variant
Dim D As Variant
Dim Targ As Range
Dim Ddate As Range
Dim Charge_Amount As Range
Dim Targdate As String
Dim EDP As String
Dim Cash As Double
Dim Backyear As Boolean
Dim Pos As Variant
Dim Cashmonth As String
Dim TY As Variant
Dim EDPM As Variant
Dim Cashcol As Long

Dim Year As Variant
Dim Month As Variant
Dim shtcount As Long

Set Todate = Range("Sorttable[To Date]")
Set Charge = Range("Sorttable[Charge Type]")
Set Duedate = Range("Sorttable[Due Date]")

Sheets("Sort_Table").Select  'select worksheet

For Each cell In Charge  'loop to find charge type
  If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
   C = cell.Value
   D = CType(C)
   
   Set Targ = cell.Offset(, 3)
   Set Ddate = cell.Offset(, 2)
   Set Charge_Amount = cell.Offset(, 4)
   Targdate = Targ.Value
   EDP = Ddate.Value
   Cash = Charge_Amount.Value
   Backyear = False
   
    If D = "Cash" Then
               
      Cashmonth = FM(EDP)
       TY = FY(EDP)
       EDPM = FM(EDP) + (FM(EDP) - 1)
       Cashcol = 28 + EDPM
       If Cashmonth = 0 Then Backyear = True
      
       If Backyear = True Then TY = FY(EDP) - 1
       If Backyear = True Then Cashcol = 51
    
       Worksheets(TY).Cells(16, Cashcol).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Cash
       Worksheets(TY).Cells(16, Cashcol - 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = EDP

‘Elseif
    ‘Another bit of unrelated code that works
‘Elseif
    ‘Another bit of unrelated code that works
‘Elseif
    ‘Another bit of unrelated code that works

‘Else 
    ‘Another bit of unrelated code that works

Worksheets("Sort_Table").Select
End if
End if
Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a sheet named `2022` in the workbook? `xlUp` is an Excel const, its value is -4162. It's right.

Comment: Yes, there's a sheet named 2022. That's the thing. I've checked all the variables  in the debug line. It's not an incorrectly declared variable because it works for the other 360/361 days in the tax year.  So obviously it's something else then. But I still have no idea what. Maybe I need to Re-dim something?

Comment: "it’s xlUp which returns -4162 rather than 5 as I expect" - why do you expect 5 ?

Comment: If you get a *subscript out of range*, for sure your worksheet index (`TY`) is wrong. Double check the content of TY (with the debugger). As you don't qualify `Worksheets`: Are you sure you want to work on the Active Workbook all the time. And some more things: Why do you handle dates as Strings? This can already be a source of error. Also: Make it a habit to give meaningful names to functions and variables. `FY`, `FM`, `TY`, `C`, `D` (and so on) may be clear for you at the moment, but they are not clear to us. And not for you in 3 months...

Comment: Surely you want `FM = TM - 1` only in May ie when `arDMY(0) < 5 AND TM = 1`

Comment: @TimWilliams because I assumed the variable it would return would be the destination row. Basically I didn't know the xlup was a constant due to being a newbie.

Comment: @CDP1802 I need it every month because tax months run from the 6th to the 5th. So if the day is 5 or less then the financial month is -1. (I'm working from the date of at the end of the month) if that makes sense. Uk tax dates are a pain to get your head around.

Comment: `Worksheets(2022)` is not the same as `worksheets("2022")`  The first is looking for the 2022nd worksheet (which presumably doesn't exist) and the second is looking for the worksheet named "2022".  `FY` returns the year as a string, but `TY = FY(EDP) - 1` gives you a numeric value.

Comment: @TimWilliams Truly! It's due to TY is Variant.

Comment: @TimWilliams That worked thanks. I knew it was something simple I just couldn't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define TY as String not Variant. Tim explained what's going on.

```
TY As String
TY = FY(EDP) - 1 ' TY will stay String and accept a new value which will be converted to String
```

Comment: It makes me shudder to see all those implicit data conversions.

Comment: @FunThomas It's VBA, you know.

Comment: Is it so hard to make an explicit conversion if you really need one? Implicit conversions are a source of so many mistakes. At least *my* code literally never has an implicit conversion. And that's for a reason.